# Test flight app crashes with libAVFAudio.dylib: AVAE_RaiseException(NSString*, ...) + 60

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, testflight, avaudioengine

I uploaded an archive on app store and am getting crash when I 'm trying to play an intro sound. I'm using `AVAudioEngine` to play the sound. When I compile and run code through Xcode everything works fine. When I upload on TestFlight and try to run my app as an internal tester my app crashes. The crash report is:

[image]

If I use `AVAudioPlayer` to play that sound it's ok. I can't understand what is the problem with `AVAudioEngine`. Any advices?

Comment: I have the same problem... Can anyone advise?

Comment: Any updates, I'm facing the same problem?

Comment: I never found a solution... I used AVAudioPlayer instead.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same exception only in the release build of my app and specific to iPhone7.
The exception seems to occur at a changing point of audio session category.
In my case, changing from

```
AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient
```

to

```
AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with:  AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker
```

I found a workaround which works at least just for me.

The following article
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65656
tells that this kind of exception occurs at initialization of multiple input audio unit.

In order to prevent initialization of multiple input audio unit,
I added the following codes before the change of audio session category

```
AudioOutputUnitStop((engine.inputNode?.audioUnit)!)
AudioUnitUninitialize((engine.inputNode?.audioUnit)!)
```

engine is the instance of `AVAudioEngine`.

I hope it will help you guys!

Comment: This isn't working and also then requires microphone access.